# Allow LAN to access External Internet, Iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I have an internal network behind my router on eth0, and I have my router connected to the internet thorugh wlan0. I can't access the internet from inside the lan, how can I fix this?

```
wlan0: 192.168.1.108
eth0:  10.1.1.0/24
```

Comment: You're not providing the operating system, and the only clue we have to go on is that it's some flavor of *nix based on the interface names.

Comment: This is supposed to be a professional IT environment (being on-topic here)...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up NAT in order for your box to act as a router. Once this is done, set the default gateway on your LAN systems to  the internal IP of the box.

Instructions here:
http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
# /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state
   --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```